# Can we overwrite list.phtml and catalog_category_view in multiple modules?

Tags: magento2, blocks, magento-catalog

Well I am vcery new to Magento,
I have a module where I have already overwritten `catalog_category_view.xml` and `list.phtml` can I use the same file with other changes in other modules if Yes how?

Answer (score 0):

Now you can override your `list.phtml` at below location,

```
app/design/frontendVendorname/themename/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml
```

Create `list.phtml` file and get content from core Magento Catalog template `list.phtml` file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="category.products.list">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module::product/list.phtml</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

You want to more information refer this link ---

**https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/how-to-override-template-phtml-files-in-magento-2/**

Hope this help you

Thanks ...

Comment: I already did this I want same list.phtml in another module as well so if I try to write code in that it doesnt reflects over there